# Ag-grid row drag (constrain to grid / prevent dragging out of grid area)

Tags: row, drag, ag-grid

All of the row drag examples in the ag-grid documentation prevent the row from being dragged out of the grid area.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/

I would to accomplish this as well. However, in my own projects the row is able to be dragged anywhere on the page.

Is there a setting, etc. I'm missing that enables this constraint?

Comment: The examples in the page are all within iframes, it's the iframe that is stopping the element from being dragged out

Comment: Wow, you're right. I'm not sure how I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without putting the table in an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Try these Settings to disable Dragging

```html
var columnDefs = [
  {
    field: 'athlete',
    suppressMovable: true,
    width: 150,
    cellClass: 'suppress-movable-col',
  },
  { field: 'age', lockPosition: true, cellClass: 'locked-col' },
  { field: 'country', width: 150 },
  { field: 'year' },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follow properties to lock the drag and drop behavior: lockPosition and suppressMovable: true.

```
columnDefs: [
   {
      field: 'athlete',
      suppressMovable: true,
      cellClass: 'suppress-movable-col',
   },
   { field: 'age', lockPosition: 'left', cellClass: 'locked-col' },
   { field: 'country' },
   { field: 'year' },
   { field: 'total', lockPosition: 'right', cellClass: 'locked-col' },
   ],
    defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
    lockPinned: true, // Dont allow pinning for this example
  },
  suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
};
```

[Sample in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xW4DcBicepolaJoS?open=main.js)
[enter link description here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-moving/)